# Yii db createCommand inset array by array key and value

Tags: база-данных, yii, запрос

Доброе время суток.
Есть функция в которую передаю массив, ключи которого совпадают с названием колонок  в таблице. Хочу сделать запрос такого типа:

```
$features = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_features SET {$feature}");
```

где

```
$feature = [
'name'=>'color',
'value'=>'black'
]
```

при выполнение этого скрипта, получаю ошибку

> CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
>   error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was:
>   INSERT INTO tbl_features SET Array

Подскажите, что не так делаю

Comment: ну он же говорит, что вы пытаетесь массив скормить, а ему строка нужна...надо наверное через `->insert` делать ........`Yii::app()->db->createCommand->insert(...`  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/database.query-builder#sec-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->insert('tbl_features', $feature);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Работает